# How can I count elements in matrix ( if elements >1)? in python

Tags: python, countelements

```
Data = matrix R
```

**First** I wanted to count elements of each row

```
countR = np.count_nonzero(R, axis=1)
```

Then, I could get matrix countR.

```
[25  2  1  2  2 55  1  2  1  2  1  1  2  2  1  1  1  1  2  2  1  2 14  1  3 ..
```

**Second,** I want to count elements in matrix 
"if element>1 "

So what I did is here

```
countR1 = pd.value_counts(countR.values, sort>1)
```

But there was an error.

How can i count elements?

Comment: Can you post some solid data we can work with?

Comment: Please take the habit to share the error you get when posting a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it easily like this:

```
y=np.array(countR)
len(y[y>1])
```

Comment: or even `sum(y>1)`

Comment: yes it would work too.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly you want to count all the elements that are larger than 1 in the matrix R.

you can filter the data-frame by doing so(to dispose of the elements that are larger than 1):

```
biggerThanOne = R[R<1]
```

you can then get the size of the array and get the number of elements:

```
biggerThanOne.size
```

if you mean you want to count the elements of countR you can practically do the same thing